# Not able to get the checkboxlist using javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, checkboxlist

I am using javascript for one of the ascx controls in my application.

The ascx controls have checkbox lists inside a panel.
I have a javascript function to handle the onclick of checkboxlist items.

I am trying to get the checkbox list as

```
    var checkBoxList = document.getElementById("<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>");
```

--> it gives checkbox list as null;
Also trying with,

```
    var checkBoxList = document.getElementById("CheckBoxList1");
```

then also the value is null.

How can I get the checkboxlist item here?

Comment: or the ID isn't correct, or are you trying to access element before it exists

Comment: when do you call this script?

Answer (score 0):

@Fabrizio Calderan is right.

There are two causes for `getElementById` to not work:

1. The ID does not exist on the DOM.
2. The DOM has not been loaded yet.

To solve #1, check your HTML source. Really.

To solve #2, you have several ways to do it:

- Recommended way: put your scripts right before you close your `body` tag. This way, all the elements will be loaded and it will work fine.
- Use the `onload` event to wait for all the elements to be loaded. The drawback is that this event waits for images to be loaded even though the DOM is ready.
- Use some library to handle the `DOMReady` event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, the control name was changed as I had these controls inside a ascx control which was added to the page.By giving the actual name, I could get the control.

Answer (score 0):

As I had the controls inside the ascx control, the control name was different from what was given in the code.

I have used the IE developer tool to get the dynamic name of the control and using this I could get the control.

Thanks for all the support. :)